In Android 14, MediaProjection popup window still shows up even though "Start now" button is pressed
When sharing the screen, a window asking for user permissions appears, but once you click "Start now", the window will still appear again in Android 14.
Expected:

Works normally as Android versions less than 14

Actual result:

App keeps asking for permission when touching on Start now button

What did I discover?

Appears twice on the virtual machine.
Appears continuously on real device and then hangs.

When I debug, it seems that on the Android 14 virtual machine, the first time after pressing the "Start now" button, the tracks are created normally, but they will not be transmitted until you press "Start now" in next time. Then the popup will no longer appear.
My project information:

React Native Version: 0.72.3
Target SDK : 33
Android os version: 14
react-native-webrtc: 118.0.7

